# Decodificar arquivos JSON em PHP sem json_decode

Tags: php, json

Atualmente estou retornando dados JSON de consultas via ElasticSearch, porém, os retornos possuem muitas informações e o uso do json_decode para poder manipular esses dados se torna muito custoso para o servidor.

Por exemplo, o uso da memória do servidor está em 5MB quando retorno o JSON puro do ES, mas ao usar o json_decode o uso de memória vai para 300MB, e o problema só aumenta conforme a quantidade de dados.

Existe alguma alternativa que não consuma tanta memória do servidor e traga o JSON exatamente da mesma forma que está escrito na string JSON original?

Comment: tenta repartir, e remover o desnecessario